# In SSMS, How to use the function that returns table name after the KEY word FROM

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, user-defined-functions

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].GetLatestTable (@id int)
    RETURNS nvarchar(max)
    BEGIN
        declare @a varchar(150)
        declare @b varchar(150)
        declare @c varchar(150)
        set @c = (select '%ID' + Cast(@id as nvarchar))
        set @a = (select top 1 name
            from sys.tables
            where name like @c
            order by create_date desc)
        set @b = '[dbo].[' + @a + ']'
    RETURN @b;
END;

SELECT * INTO #table1
from 
    (SELECT * FROM GetLatestTable (1456)) as temp
```

I want to store the latest table which was created with its name containing a particular integer, into a temporary table.

Sample table name looks like: `[database].[dbo].[RQ39411ID1367]`

I need it from a function because I need to use this function for other table names later in my query.

Please help me change my syntax as well for SSMS.

Comment: The syntax looks like T-SQL, and the fact you've used the SSMS tag also suggests you're using SQL Server. Alas, in SQL Server, User defined functions can't execute dynamic SQL... Also, seems like you're attempting to use a scalar UDF as a table UDF, which obviously will not work.

Comment: Also, the fact that you would want something like this suggest you have a terribly poor design for your database... If you could [edit] your question with a sample of the table names you have and what you expect to get back from the function, perhaps someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have added sample table name in the question. 
I need the latest table created in the db with its name containing a specific integer. 
I want to store it in a temporary table.

Comment: This simply can't be done using a function. It can be done with a stored procedure, if you really want to, but I would suggest thinking what got you in that mess to begin with, and consider a re-design of the database.

Comment: Its either a re-design (best) or dynamic SQL...

Comment: @ZoharPeled while we extract the table from a source system, frequently and store it in SQL, the table name is automatically generated. The only constant in the tablename is the ID number (the parameter we pass in above function). 
We need to perform further data transformation on the extracted table. So need the latest table in that case.

Comment: A different (terrible) approach would be to create a `view` that uses the most recent table as its base. It still requires dynamic SQL.

Comment: @HABO I thought of the same. But then created a temporary table with pre-defined schema and then used dynamic SQL query to insert data into it.
I could not find a way to create a temporary table dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't redesign the database, you can do something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].GetLatestTable (@id int)
    RETURNS nvarchar(261)
AS
BEGIN

RETURN (
    SELECT TOP 1 quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(t.name)
    FROM sys.tables As t
    JOIN sys.schemas As s
        ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    WHERE t.name LIKE '%ID' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(11))
    ORDER BY t.create_date DESC
);

END
```

and use it like this

```
DECLARE @LastTableName nvarchar(216) = dbo.GetLatestTable(1456);
```

Comment: How do I get to using the Table Name to execute the below query

(
SELECT * INTO  #table1
from ........... 
)

Need help in using the table name

Comment: If your temporary table doesn't exist - `SELECT [dbo].GetLatestTable(1) As LatestTableName INTO #TempTable` If it already exists - 
`INSERT INTO #TempTable(LatestTableName) VALUES ([dbo].GetLatestTable(2))`

Comment: The above query copies the 'tablename' into the TempTable and not the data of the table with that tablename. This is my primary issue.

Comment: Well, then, you'd have to construct a dynamic select...into statement for the table name you've got back from the function. That can't be done inside a user defined function

Answer (score 0):

If a function or procedure is used to get the table_name and dynamic SQL used to insert data into `#table1`, then you need to note that the scope of temp table in `select * into #table` is within the scope of dynamic SQL execution. This means you cannot use `#table` beyond the dynamic SQL, even in the same session. So use a global temp table e.g. `##table1` instead of a local temp table.

Assuming used a function `dbo.gettablename` to pull out the table name gives:

```
DECLARE @SqCom nvarchar(255) = 'select * into ##table1 from ' + dbo.gettablename(1456)
EXEC (@SqCom);
SELECT * FROM ##table1;
```

Comment: This is not working in my case. I am able to get the table name from the function but unable to create the temporary table. I am using SSMS. 
Can you suggest something?

Comment: Can you share the error,

Are you using local temporary table or global temporary table in dynamic sql?

Answer (score -1):

Hope this works for your case:

```
SELECT *, GetLatestTable (1456) INTO #table1
```

Comment: What is `*` going to give?

Comment: The created function returns a table name from the db.
So I want to get all the columns with that table name and store it in to a temporary table #table1